# Setting each tab on TabBarController a different colour when selected?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar and want to set tints that are indipendent based on selected tab, I know I can tint them so they all change to 1 new color, however I havent been able to get them to each take on their own colour when selected. Is there a way to do this?

currently have this, where the tint is just white, i want to tint each one indipendently

[image: mybar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your Tabbar item and in attribute inspector set both `Selected Image` and `Image` for bar item check below Image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Yes thats set already as thats how i get the icons to display, im talking about tinting them different colors depending on which is selected. for example when i click the weight it tints orange, when i click the timer it tints purple, when i click the arm it tints green etc.

Comment: @infernouk What i means to say is make image of your selected tab item with color that you want and set that image in Selected Image option.

Comment: ah i see, is this the best way rather than using code to recolour?

Comment: @infernouk This is easiest way to achieve what you want,if it is still not work then set your image rendering mode to original image from attributes insepector

Comment: Thanks this did it!

Comment: @infernouk Welcome mate :)