# How do I fully customise TabBar in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I need to customise `TabBar` in my iOS Application as shown in the image[image]

I need to change the background colour, unselected image tint colour and selected image tint colour. How can this be done

Comment: did you try this [link](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-how-to-customize-tab-bar-background-appearance/)

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to set `barTintColor` and `tintColor` property of `UITaBbar`.

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = .blue //Background Color
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = .yellow //Selected Item tint color
```

**Note:** If you have image for both state means default and selected, then set both the images for its sets, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40742553/6433023) to set selected image for tabbar item. Now set the `Render mode` of both the image to `Original Image` in assets, if you don't know how to set that check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38560183/6433023).